# Can't upload new sketch

Tags: arduino-uno, uploading, upload

Recently I have unsoldered most connector pins there are on the arduino uno board.
However, when I now attempt to upload a new sketch (works when I upload it to another model) it gives me the following error:

```
> avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfa
```

I would like you take a look at my arduino board to see whether I have unsoldered important pins which might have to be connected.

Also when I try to upload a new sketch the 'L'-LED doesn't flash but the RX one.

(BTW: Yes I've set the settings to the correct board, port etc...)

[image]

Thanks for any solution attempts!

Comment: Clean the board up using solder wick -- if there are shorts like those mentioned in Jot's answer, it may clear them up.  Also, if you need an Arduino to solder into a circuit, just start with one that doesn't come with pins soldered on already -- eg, a Nano or Micro.  You can buy half a dozen of each for the cost of the time to take the pins off an Uno.

Comment: If I may suggest, there are "minimal" boards around you can buy for a couple of dollars that just have the basic processor on them. This could be a better solution than heating up your Uno (probably quite a lot) to get rid of the existing pins.

Answer (score 1):

Removing there pin headers should not cause any sketch upload issue. I have done it many times.

You did try uploading BEFORE unsoldering the headers right ?

However looking at the desoldering job you did, my guess is that you applied too much heat or cut a trace on the PCB while doing it.

Can you upload a high resolution of the back side of the board?

What I would try is to take a known good 328p chip and replace the one on this board with it and try uploading again.

Answer (score 0):

Pin 0(RX) and 1(TX) and the RESET pins are important to upload a sketch. Can you check those carefully with a magnifier ? Perhaps there is some solder that shortcuts to something else, or perhaps you damaged a copper trace.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the schematic, the TX/RX leds are driven directly by the atmega16u and are not connected to the TX/RX lines of the 328p.  That would seem to indicate the 16u has a problem so it's a good place to double check. The lines that run to the TX/RX of the 328p run from pins 8 - 9 of the 16u. I assume that this ran previous to the fatal 'surgery'? I don't suppose you loaded something simple, like the led flash program before surgery?  Just curious, are you hard wiring it to something?

Answer (score 0):

Try to unplug the IC and the plug it again.

I think that you have removed the IC off of the board. If it doesn't work then buy a new ATmega328P IC and replace it with the old one and then try again.